# How to add css for CheckBoxFor on MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I add Css style for checkBoxFor on MVC?

This is My View

```
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => 
               Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].IsCheck)
               @Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].SelectedCategoryName;


                @Html.HiddenFor(m => 
                Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].SelectedCategoryID);
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].SelectedCategoryName);
```

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => 
               Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].IsCheck, new { @class = "yourcss" })

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].IsCheck, new { @class = "myclass" })
```

Or you can also add inline CSS but i recommend using the first approach.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.CategoryList.Categories[i].IsCheck, new { style="width:100px;height:25px" })
```